# Special case of double checked locking?

Tags: java, multithreading, double-checked-locking

So I have this code where lockMap is a `ConcurrentHashMap`

```
    //Creation of locks
Lock getLock(String key) {
    Lock lock = lockMap.get(key);
    if (lock == null) {
        synchronized (lockMap) {
            lock = lockMap.get(key);
            if (lock == null) {
                lock = new ReentrantLock();
                lockMap.put(key, lock);
            }
        }
    }

    return lock;
}
```

During a code review someone mentioned that this is a typical case of DCL, because, since the compiler can reorder events, it is possible that the lock is not yet fully initialized when inserted in the map, then the next thread requesting the same lock could potentially not yet be fully initialized.

Now, the problem I have with this is that this problem is a common problem with multi threaded applications: get something from a map and if not there create and add.

1. Is this really a case of a DCL?
2. If so, how do you solve it. (easy and dumb way we used is to create a pool of locks and when one is extracted from the pool a new one is inserted)
3. If so again, is it fixed in java8

Comment: Reorder which events?

Comment: why do you query the lock twice and why on earth do you have locks in a dictionary? To make any sense at all the entire operation should first obtain a lock not in the dicionary e.g. synchonized method and then lock the lock before returning.

Comment: It is DCL [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking#Usage_in_Java), however as @rolfl showed, there is no need to `synchronize` on the `ConcurrentHashMap`.

Comment: Also what do you mean "is it fixed in java 8"? This has nothing to do with the version of java.

Comment: To Vidstige.
Map operations are thread safe. Not what's around it.
2 threads using same key get null. both create lock, both insert safely the value in map, but externally use 2 different locks which is bad.

Comment: Also, the use of concurrent map is to minimize and possible avoid costly synchronization. that's why i dont want to synchronize the method. The point of all of this is to increase throughput by minimizing syncs.

Comment: the DCL has to do with the java mem model. Java code is ultimately interpreted in ASM. Ops can be reordered depending on how the code is optimized hence the DCL issue. If java can guaranty that object creation results in no reordering of ASM ops then all is good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fact that you have locks in a ConcurrentHashMap is.... confusing, but, assuming you know what you are doing with them, the better way to write this would be:

```
Lock getLock(String key) {
    Lock lock = lockMap.get(key);
    if (lock == null) {
        lock = new ReentrantLock();
        Lock race = lockMap.putIfAbsent(key, lock);
        if (race != null) {
            //there was a race, we lost.
            lock = race;
        }
    }
    return lock;
}
```

Note the use of the [putIfAbsent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#putIfAbsent-K-V-) atomic operation. We also optimistically  create a new Lock, but then if we lost the race-condition, we throw it out, and use the race winner lock.

Comment: does not compile as nothing is returned

Answer (score 0):

So somehow i did not get any notifications so sorry about the late response.
I thought of the put if absent, however, there is a cost of always creating an object for nothing (most of the time) so i wanted to avoid this.
but i guess the cost is minimal so i will use this solution.